# issue with normalizing variable

Tags: r, normalization

I am trying to normalize a variable using Box-Cox. However, I am receiving an error message:

```
boxcox_obj <- boxcox(alive_data_4$mosslpadeq)
Error in estimate_boxcox_lambda(x, ...) : x must be positive
```

I read online that you can get this message when the variable has negative values. However, that is not the case with this variable (see frequency below).

```
 table(alive_data_4$mosslpadeq)

   0   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90  100 
 766  635 2141 1756 3355 1913 2095 1400 4498 1361 2228
```

Can someone advise?

Comment: What package are you using for the `boxcox` function? That's not in base R.

Comment: some would say that zero is nonpositive -- does it work after omitting the zeros or adding 1 to the vector? (you also have ten unique values so its going to be hard finding a useful transformation)

Comment: ... or more accurately 11 values ;/

Comment: I am using bestNormalize. @user20650, it did work when I removed the 0's! I don't know if I could justify removing those values though. If none of the transformations really normalize it, would the next best thing be to binarize it?

Comment: Maybe `x[x == 0] <- .Machine$double.eps`? (With `alive_data_4$mosslpadeq`, not `x`)

Comment: @D.Fowler; why do you need to normalize it -- from a quick look at the help pages of bestNormalize::boxcox I am taking this to mean transform to normally distributed? If you must then adding a value would be better than removing the zeros as this should geive the same scaled value. What is your variable -- it only seems to get measured in steps of 10 -- could you treat it as ordinal?

Comment: @user20650, yes, what I want to do is look at the variable in a continuous fashion and run a linear regression. If I added a variable, wouldn't the distribution be the same though? And yes, I could do an ordinal regression. My experience is that often the proportional hazard ratio is often violated so I wanted to avoid that approach if possible.

Comment: @D.Fowler; yes adding a constant and then transforming will give you the same scaled variable but it is arguably better than removing the zeros.  Also remember that it is the conditional distribution rather than the distribution of the raw variable where there are some assumptions of normality (for inference).

Comment: thank you @user20650. can you clarify what you mean by "it is the conditional distribution rather than the distribution of the raw variable where there are some assumptions of normality." I'm not sure what you mean by "conditional distribution."

Comment: @D.Fowler; in regression, for inference, there is not an assumption that an outcome Y is normally distributed, the assumption is that Y|X~N(X\beta, \sigma). This assumption is often represented as y_i = b_0 + b_1X_i + \eps_i, \eps~N(0,\sigma) i.e. check the residuals to get an estimate not the raw variable

Comment: thank you @user20650. Your explanation is really helpful. :)